# Meteor & Semantic UI - How do I give some transition effect to specific template after modal pops up & click 'Approval' button?

Tags: templates, session, meteor, semantic-ui

**1. What I want to do :** Give a transition effect with Semantic-UI to template A(template 'card') after a modal pops up & user click 'Approval' button.

**2. What I did first :** Save template instance of template A into Session, get that template instance using Session.get(), and give some transition effect in modal initializer inside of template B(template 'modalremove')`s onRendered function.

**3. How I did :**

```
    Template.card.events ({
        "click #remove-item": function (event, template) {
            event.preventDefault();

            Session.set('removeTemplate', template); // Error
            Session.set('removeItem',this);

            $('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');
        }
    });

    Template.modalremove.onRendered(function () {
         $('.ui.basic.modal')
            .modal({
                closable  : true,
                blurring  : true,
                onDeny    : function(){
                    return;
                },
                onApprove : function() {

                    var removeTemplate = Seesion.get('removeTemplate');
                    if (removeTemplate == null) {
                        console.log("removeTemplate is null");
                        return;
                    }

                    removeTemplate.$('.card').transition({
                        animation  : 'fade left',
                        duration   : '650ms',
                        onComplete : function() {

                            Meteor.call("removeItem", Session.get('removeItem'));

                        }
                    });
                }
            });  

});
```

**4. Result :** I got 'Uncaught RangeError' where I tried to save a template instance to Session.

```
    ejson.js:500 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

**5. What I want to know :**  How do I  give some transition effect to template 'card' after modal pops up & click 'Approval' button?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very unique pattern. What problem are you trying to solve that can't be solved with more direct Meteor techniques, for example just putting the template inside an `{{#if }}` block or even a [dynamic template](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)?

Comment: I would like to add to what Michel said and suggest that you take a look at what an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my question more precise!